# Remove code created using eval

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval

I wonder how it is possible, to remove code that was created using eval. I am aware using eval is not best practice. Anyway...

Let's say I have the following variable: `var code = '...';`
In "code" some Variables are created and a click Listener is attached to a 
button. Then I say eval(code). This works fine so far.

Unfortunately I did not find any way to "unbind" the click listener or delete 
the variables. It would be great, if all the code created with eval, could be
deleted at once. Any suggestions?

Comment: Variables generally can't be deleted. If you do this eval inside a function, they'll just naturally go out of scope. Unbinding handlers depends on how you bound them, and there's plenty of information online if you search. If you're hoping for a simple way to reverse your `eval`, it doesn't exist.

Comment: Im curious, is the eval'ed code static? If so why eval?

Comment: There's no way of un-running code. What are you asking for? Removing all the side effects of an arbitrary chunk of code you've thrown into `eval()`?